# .bind function with CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

When I try to convert the following snippet of code ...

```
result.pause = function() {        
  cachedValue = this();
  isPaused(true);
}.bind(result);
```

using http://js2coffee.org/ it returns

```
result.pause = ->
  cachedValue = this()
  isPaused true
.bind(result)
```

However that code is incorrect when you try to compile it you get back Error Unexpected '.'

What would the correct way to use the .bind function in this situation using CoffeeScript be?

Comment: Try putting the function in `()`.  `pause = (function(){}).bind()`

Comment: You're converting from a language you know into a language you don't know? Seems backwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
result.pause = (->
  cachedValue = this()
  isPaused true)
.bind(result)
```