# How do I make my javascript method available to my other backbone methods?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

For some reason I am not able to access the defined `@$inputTestDiv` variable and `isStringEmpty` method in my `backbone.js` code. If I use it outside of the `$.ajax` success method I can use them fine. Is there a scoping issue here I'm not aware of or is it a syntax issue? Thank you!

**testapp.js.coffee**

```
  el = $('body')
  TestApp.app.appView = new TestApp.code.views.AppView { el } if el.length
```

**test_app.js.coffee**

```
class TestApp.code.views.AppView extends Backbone.View

  events:
    'click a#test_btn' : 'doSomething'

  initialize: ->
    @setupElements()

  setupElements: ->
    @$inputTestDiv = @$el.find 'input#test_div'

  isStringEmpty: (str) ->
    str.trim().length == 0

  doSomething: =>
    $('input#test_div').append("WORKS") if @isStringEmpty("test") #this works
    $.ajax
      type : 'GET'
      dataType : 'json'
      url : '/users'
      success: (result) ->
        if @isStringEmpty(result) # browser can't find isStringEmpty method
          @$inputTestDiv.html("YES") # browser says @$inputTestDiv is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely this is scope issue. you have to use as follows:

```
doSomething: =>
    var self = this;
    $('input#test_div').append("WORKS") if @isStringEmpty("test") #this works
    $.ajax
        type : 'GET'
        dataType : 'json'
        url : '/users'
        success: (result) ->
             if self.isStringEmpty(result) 
                self.$el.find('#inputTestDiv').html("YES");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the assignment of `@`, or `this` in JavaScript: in your `success` callback, `this` is not your view object because the callback is called directly, not as a property of your view object, nor as a bound function.

To make it so, take a look at [this answer on function binding in CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14904241/3150057).

Alternatively, you can assign `self = this` (or a more meaningful name, perhaps `view`) before the call to `$.ajax`, and replace uses of `@` with said variable within the `success` callback.